# Finding previous and next li with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, kendo-ui, jquery-events

I have an uncertain amount of nested ul and li tags like:

```
<ul>    
    <li>5
        <ul>
            <li>2
                <ul>
                    <li>1
                    </li>
                    <li>4
                        <ul>
                            <li>3
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>7
        <ul>
            <li>9
                <ul>
                    <li>14
                    <li>
                </ul>
            <li>11
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Kendo ui treeview and it returns me the element where the l was dropped (it might be a element inside the li because I have some spans in each one).

What I need is to know the previous and next li through DOM and **Javascript** to save the new order of elements.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I have jquery loaded but I get a dom object, not a jquery one... I don't think so but i'm a beginner at this so ... :)

Comment: Have you looked at using jQuery in noConflict mode?  This allows you to have multiple versions on the same page and work with other Javascript libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which event you were using, but it should be "dragend".  That way you should be able to detect the parent li and then just get all of it's children to reorder.

Check out this fiddle here.  Is this closer to what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/burkeholland/CrRUz/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var parentLi = $(e).closest('li');
var previousLi = parentLi.prev()
var nextLi = parentLi.next();
```

Where `e` is the element receiving the drop.

Comment: thanks Alexandre but it isn't working completly. I think it isn't entering in the parents childs to look for a match so I'm getting no results most of the time (doing console.log on chrome) thanks

Comment: So if the next <li> sibling contains an <ul> you then want to find the next <li> inside it?